# Calling a method on a value stored in a std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary

In the following code:

```
class Abc {
    int x;
    void clear() { x=0; }
}


map<string, Abc> mymap;
Abc abc1;
abc1.x = 12;
mymap[1] = abc1;

map<string, Abc>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
it->second.clear();

map<string, Abc>::iterator it2 = mymap.begin();
cout << it2->second.x; // what will this display?
```

Supposing I have no errors (map is not empty, etc.), will the call to clear modify the element stored in the map, or a copy?

I know that if I stored `Abc*` pointers in the map, there would be no problem, it would print `0`, but I can't figure if `second` returns a value or a reference, and if I'm clearing the value that's in the map or a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

`second` is a reference - you're modifying the element stored in the map. Or, to be specific, `*it` is a reference to the `std::pair` stored in the map, `second` is the actual element.

Comment: I guess this is the purpose of iterators to allow this, right ? (and the reason why at some point a function might return an iterator where a non-C++ programmer would have expected to receive "the result"). Is there any case where we have read-only iterators and is there a way to tell it is so by looking at the std::* documentation (e.g. const_iterator) ?

Comment: @sylvainulg: On the second question, no. You return an iterator when you'd want to access adjoining elements; you'd return a reference to the result if you want to be able to modify the result.

Comment: @sylvainulg: If an iterator is categorized as an "input iterator" in docs, you cannot assign to its contents. E.g. istream_iterator which is used to extract values from a stream. This is in addition to const_iterator versions, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
map<string, Abc> mymap;
Abc abc1;
abc1.x = 12;
mymap[1] = abc1;
```

Compilation error :

Because the key type is `string`, but you passing `1` to `mymap` as key.

```
cout << it2->second.x; // what will this display?
```

It will display the value of `x` : 0

This is equivalent to this:

```
Abc a;
a.x = 12;
a.clear();
cout << a.x ; //prints 0, because a.clear() made it 0!
```

Answer (score 0):

It will modify the element in the map, .second is not a function it's a member of a std::pair structure

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try? You can write a copy constructor for `Abc` that prints out a message when the object is copied:

```
class Abc {
public:
    Abc(const Abc & other) 
     : x(other.x)
    {
        std::cout << "copying" << std::endl;
    }
    void clear() { x=0; }
private:
    int x;
}
```

Using this, you can find out if your object is getting copied. You should do things like that to learn how things work.